# how to set string list into metadata using grpc in dart

Tags: dart, go, grpc, grpc-go, grpc-dart

I have a golang grpc server. The metadata definition in grpc golang is a struct of map[string][]string, which can get a string list value with a given key.

but in my dart(flutter app) client, the dart grpc metadata definition is a struct of map<string, string>. Then I can only passing a string into metadata value

how can I set string list into metadata in grpc dart?

Comment: There's an [issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dart/issues/627) on the GitHub repo for the Dart gRPC implementation that reflects this issue. Headers should support repeated string values.